# PostGIS query using ST_Dwithin and output to a Table and add distances in a separate column

Tags: postgis

I am struggling with how to add the actual distances to a table I create with a query. Here is what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE cdot.rail_risk AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t2.gid) t2.gid, t2.status, t2.railroad, t2.geom
FROM cdot.streams t1
    LEFT JOIN cdot.rail_lines_100k t2 ON ST_DWithin(t1.geom, t2.geom, 100)
WHERE t2.status = 'IN SERVICE'

ORDER BY t2.gid, ST_Distance(t1.geom, t2.geom);
```

What I am trying to do is add a numeric column 'dist' (rounded to 0 digits) and populate the distances. I tried several different alternatives and none of them worked. Here is one attempt that failed:

```
CREATE TABLE cdot.rail_risk AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t2.gid) t2.gid, t2.status, t2.railroad, t2.geom
FROM cdot.streams t1
    LEFT JOIN cdot.rail_lines_100k t2 ON ST_DWithin(t1.geom, t2.geom, 100)
WHERE t2.status = 'IN SERVICE'
ADD COLUMN dist numeric
UPDATE rail_risk SET dist= ROUND((ST_Distance (t1.geom, t2.geom)):: numeric,0)
ORDER BY dist;
```

I am very new at postgis and am trying to learn this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do mean by "none of them worked"? Did you get an error - if so what message? Did a query run but update no records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what have you wrote, but it's far away from correct sql query. 'Add column' is option of 'alter table', update in select will not work that way... If you need to write sql query please read at least fundamentals of SQL.

You need another column just add it in select clause...

```
CREATE TABLE cdot.rail_risk AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t2.gid) t2.gid, t2.status, t2.railroad, t2.geom, ROUND((ST_Distance (t1.geom, t2.geom)):: numeric,0) as dist
FROM cdot.streams t1
    LEFT JOIN cdot.rail_lines_100k t2 ON ST_DWithin(t1.geom, t2.geom, 100)
WHERE t2.status = 'IN SERVICE'
ORDER BY (dist);
```

Comment: Jendrusk, it took me a while to understand your answer but it was exactly what I needed. This is the first time I am writing in SQL so I am learning. You tell me to read fundamentals - that is what I am doing. I am taking an intro course this semester. I have written in other languages but this is new. Please don't be so patronizing, and thank you for answering.

Comment: Ok, you're learning - It's good, but do it right. Your query looks like 'first query of my life' made by copy-paste one after another random parts of few queries which are doing a part of what-you-want... if you'll read some fundamentals you'll see how trivial is this query you wrote. After few hours of reading you'll see I'm right.Sorry if you feel offended